# Moving image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image and I want that when I click on it, the image moves according to the mouse and when I release the mouse the image stays in that position. Can anyone guide me on how to do that in Javascript?

Comment: do you want make the image drag and dropable, like https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried? Please paste in your original comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.logo').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="logo" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" alt="Google">
```

Comment: I want that when I release the mouse the image stays in that position

Comment: @user7779120 : Atleast try that yourself !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery UI Library as [Anil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1328605/anil) have mentioned before in the comment. Give it a try to this one !

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    #draggable {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#draggable").draggable();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>You can drag & drop the image below</p><hr>

  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <img src="http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/u/uno-unc2.gif" width="100%" height="100%">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```